# See if 2 images have the same color distribution

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have 2 images: the first one is the model, the second one is the target.
I want to see if they have the same color distribution, independently from brightness.
How can I do it? with variance maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [compareHist](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=comparehist#comparehist) in a colours space like HSV and compare H (and S).
I believe this is very well explained [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html?highlight=histogram).
Good luck

Comment: Why would you use a HSV histogram? If the image contains any grayish areas, the H component is essentially noise. If it contains dark areas, the H and S components are both noise.

Comment: It was just a suggestion and I do not know precisely what kind of image user1275896 uses, but it seemed to me that he/she wanted to get rid of the brightness component. Maybe I am wrong, but I think this could be achieved by using hue.